# Something is wrong with my class. I'm a beginner

Tags: java

I'm creating a roulette game, and I am testing things out.

I have a Game class that builds and set everything ready. It also builds a test-player named Passenger57 that only bets on black.

Somehow, I can't get the Game-class to call on Passenger57 and make it place a bet.
The table returns an empty list of bets!

What am I overlooking?

**GAME**

```
package Roulette;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Game {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Table table = new Table();
    BinBuilder bb = new BinBuilder();
    Passenger57 p57 = new Passenger57(table);
    p57.placeBets();    // <-- This guy is not doing much!
// ETC ETC//
```

**PASSENGER57**

```
package Roulette;

public class Passenger57 {

public Table table;
public Outcome black;
public Bet bet;

public Passenger57(Table table){
    this.table = new Table();
    this.black = new Outcome("Black", 1);

}

void placeBets(){
    Bet bet = new Bet(100, black);
    table.placeBet(bet);
}

 void win(Bet bet){
    System.out.println("You've won: " + bet.winAmount());
}

 void lose(Bet bet){
     System.out.println("You lost!"+bet.loseAmount()+ ":/");

}


}
```

**Thank you so much for helping out a beginner stumbling around!**

Just in case you need it

**TABLE**

```
package Roulette;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Table {

public int limit = 1000;
public LinkedList<Bet> bets;

public Table(){
    bets = new LinkedList<Bet>();
}

public  boolean isValid(Bet bet){
    int sum = 0;
    for(Bet bett: bets){
        sum += bett.amountBet;
    }
    return (sum>limit);
}

public void placeBet(Bet bet){
        this.bets.add(bet);
}

ListIterator<Bet> iterator(){
    return bets.listIterator();

}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In class **Passenger57** you should change

```
public Passenger57(Table table){
    this.table = new Table(); // <- here is your fault
    black = new Outcome("Black", 1); 
}
```

to

```
public Passenger57(Table table){
    this.table = table;
    black = new Outcome("Black", 1); 
}
```

Comment: Aha! I'm creating a new table! Thank you so much for helping me see that! :D

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
this.table = new Table()
```

by

```
this.table = table in Passenger57(Table table)
```